# No response when uploading relatively large files to server

Tags: php, html, ajax, file-upload, upload

I have a page to upload images to my server(http://neiol.1ufh.com/) in the uploads folder (http://neiol.1ufh.com/uploads) however I noticed that I can only upload images of about 160kb in size if higher than that I get no response not even the response that comes when uploading files with size bigger than 2M, (2M is the max file post size on the server).

Comment: Server response: `413 Request Entity Too Large`

Comment: I only get this response when uploading large .txt files. What file size did you try, is it an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to answer your question, but you NEED to check on the security. I recommend setting the site down right now before fixing it. I just could upload and execute `apac.php`, which only contained this PHP:

```
<?php echo "This is a really bad security issue"; ?>
```

But I could be a malicious person and break your website. Check it out: http://neiol.1ufh.com/uploads/apac.php

NOTE: I put this in an answer since the comment is too small for the formatting and everything,

Comment: How did you upload this .php file?

Comment: Created `apac.php` locally, clicked "Browse" and selecting it. You can also upload any other type of files. Same with [`matrix.html`](http://neiol.1ufh.com/uploads/matrix.html) (;

Comment: Oh I understand, thanks. I should limit the number of allowed formats. Have you tried to upload Images of sizes about 1M what do you get?

Comment: You are encouraged to do so by reading the [MIME format with Fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php), not the extension. I could just upload an 1.7MB image on your form with the answer `The file galaxy.jpg has been uploaded` and [it's indeed there](http://neiol.1ufh.com/uploads/galaxy.jpg)

Comment: I get no response when uploading images of size exceeding about 160kb is it an issue with my browser.

Comment: You should then check with other browsers like Chrome / Firefox and enabling / disabling some extensions to check it out.

Comment: I have tried it on both Chrome and Internet Explorer 11, still no result, By the way I am not sure  its a browser issue because I can upload images to websites like twitter and facebook just fine.